# Limit tends to infinity problem.

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

[Here is a problem about limit tends to infinity.I have given an answer.Please let me know,if this is correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gy40.jpg)

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I want to check if my answer is correct.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPanf.jpg

Comment: Your answer is correct, but I believe you mean $1+3^{-\infty}$ in the denominator in second last line.

Comment: yeah,I think so.

Comment: I dk  why someone voted down. I think  down votes should require written reasons and be subject to review.

Comment: Note that limits don't tend to anything. They're not moving around doing the cha-cha-cha. They either exist or don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is correct. Just write
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{3^n - 3^{-n}}{3^n + 3^{-n}}= \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{3^n}{3^n}\cdot \frac{1 - 3^{-2n}}{1 + 3^{-2n}} = 1$$
and add that $\lim_{n\to \infty} 3^{-2n} =0$. I personally would avoid to write something like $3^{-\infty}$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes your answer is correct. Any integer divided by zero is infinity except zero.

Either it's 1/0 or -2/0.